# Where are people using the expression 過得 / 过得?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

MDBG lists [过得](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%BF%87%E5%BE%97), but during my time in China, I have never heard this expression. Where in China is it used and what are the local meanings of it?

> 过得    guò dé  How are you getting by? / How's life? / contraction of 過得去|过得去, can get by / tolerably well / not too bad

Comment: bkrs:How are you getting by?
How’s life?
  **contraction of 过得去**  , can get by
tolerably well
not too bad,  find many examples at bkrs,  "现代汉语词典":过得去（１）无阻碍，通得过：这条胡同儿很宽，汽车～。（２）（生活）不很困难（３）说得过去：准备一些茶点招待客人，也就～了（４）过意得去（多用于反问）：看把您累成那个样子，叫我心里怎么～呢？also in other online dictionaries,

Comment: combination of 过去 （经过 pass through，过 with  simple direction complement（简单趋向补语） 去）with 得 used as potential complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 过得 and 过得去 are common in China, but 过得 and 过得去 can have different meanings.

过得: 生活得(怎么样), how one's life lives; For example, 你过得怎么样？：How are you getting along? or how is your life (you live)?

过得去: to get through or get by; It has literal and metaphorical meaning. The literal meaning is to physically get through and metaphorically, it means to get through a difficult situation. For example, 我过得去 could simple mean 'I can get it through'. 我生活还过得去： 'Things in my life are able to get through.' It implies that your life is okay or not too bad.

Comment: 'common in China' -> all over China?

Comment: @thymaro, yes, at least within mainland.